# Concatenate all 2 dimensional values in a dictionary. (Output is Torch tensor)

Tags: python, dictionary, torch

I want to concatenate all 2 dimensional values in a dictionary.

The number of rows of these values is always the same.

```py
D = {'a': [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
     'b': [[1, 1],
           [1, 1],
           [1, 1]],
     'c': [[2, 2, 2, 2],
           [2, 2, 2, 2],
           [2, 2, 2, 2]]
}
```

And the output must be form of a torch tensor.

```py
tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import torch
print(torch.cat(tuple([torch.tensor(D[name]) for name in D.keys()]), dim=1))
```

Output:

```py
tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain    
l = []
for i in range(len(D)):
    t = [ D[k][i] for k in D ] 
    l.append( list(chain.from_iterable(t)) )
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
```